# I don't understand my for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

My question may silly, so apologize in advance. My instructions were to build a function that iterated over a queue of functions.  The answer is at the bottom....below the puzzlers array.

Can someone explain why the command in the for-loop is **input = queue.shift()(input);**.  I understand that I had to use the shift method to empty the queue.  This exercise was confusing to me to begin with, but creating **input = queue.shift()(input);** is still strange to me.  any fundamental explanations would be greatly appreciated.  If you need more info, please let me know.....thank you in advance.

```
var puzzlers = [
    function ( a ) { return 8*a - 10; },
    function ( a ) { return (a-3) * (a-3) * (a-3); },
    function ( a ) { return a * a + 4; },
    function ( a ) { return a % 5; }
];

var applyAndEmpty = function( input, queue ) {
    var length = queue.length;
    for(var i = 0; i<length; i++){
        input = queue.shift()(input);
    }
    return input;
};
alert(applyAndEmpty(2, puzzlers));
```

Comment: Please retitle your question.

Comment: Above comment still applies.

Answer (score 5):

`queue` is an array, so `queue.shift()` takes the first item out of the array (removing it) and returns it.

Now, since `queue` is holding functions, you're telling whatever function was at the beginning of `queue` to run with a parameter of `input`.

For a more concrete example, lets say the first item in `queue` was a function called `function1`. You can think of `queue.shift()` as being replaced by `function1` once it evaluates—so `queue.shift()(input);` becomes `function1(input);`

Comment: `.shift()` is also removing that item from the array.